# R replacement error in for loop calculating IRR despite error checking and working simple example

Tags: r, loops

I am lost again and would appreciate any help.

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4), year=c(2010,2011,2012,2013), time=c(4,6,7,2), Value1=c(10,20,30,40), Value2=c(100,200,300,400))
df$IRR <- NA

library(FinancialMath)
for (i in 1:length(df$ID)){
  df$IRR[i] <- IRR(cf0=df$Value1[i],cf=df$Value2[i],times=df$time[i])
}
```

This is to calculate the IRRs for the respective IDs and put them in the $IRR column. The issue here is, that this examples is actually working!

Whenever I do it with my actual data (can not post this here), i get the error:
`In df$IRR[i] <- IRR(cf0 = df$Value1[i], cf = df$Value2[i],  : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

In fact, despite the error, the for loop still calculates the IRRs and puts them in the column. My ultimate goal though is to make this for loop part of a function which i run over a list of data frames (all with same structure) using `purrr::map()`.

There, the error is

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "IRR", value = NA) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
In addition: Warning message:
In df$IRR[i] <- IRR(cf0 = df$Value1[i], cf = df$Value2[i],  :
```

and the function does not run through my list of data frames. I checked the function for errors and I would appreciate your help assuming that my function, which entails the IRR for loop, is not the problem.

I do not know whether my specification of the problem is good enough but I would appreciate if you could maybe hint me to some issues that you can come up with.

My df in my original data is a modified original pdata.frame (package:plm) which is converted to a normal data frame before the point it enters the IRR for loop. Is it possible that some attributes from this former pdata.frame obscure the functionality of my for loop or own function?

I have searched everywhere to solve the rather generic `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` error but have not found a solution.

Thank you for your help and best regards,

cork

Comment: Can you post a code example that produces those errors?

Comment: Note in documentation: `Uses polyroot function to solve equation given by series of cash flows, meaning that in the case of having a negative IRR, multiple answers may be returned.` - multiple values don't fit in a single cell, as long as they are not converted into a list or paste together into a string (their might be more options). Therefore R puts the first element of the result values in your cell and will ignore the other results of the function. (For example set Value2 to negative and you will get two values as result)

Comment: Hello @tamtam , that is it! Thank you. I noticed that it does not handle negative IRRs the way I want to either so I applied jrvFinance::irr as well as allowed my own function i mapped over my list of data frames to also be NA (makes sense in my case) using possibly(). Your answer truly helped though! I had in the back of my mind that it had to be the IRR formula but couldn't fix it. Thank you.